# PHP form handling of checkbox values to cart

Tags: php, checkbox, cart

I have what seems to be a unique situation. I would like to have a check box form that shows on a page:

Exam Study Guide - Add $100.00 "check box here"
Online Test Simulator - Add $200.00"check box here"

I would like to be able to choose either box or both and have the total dollar amount sent to my shopping cart via a submit button.

I have been trying to create an array and then add the amounts within the array so that they can be passed to the cart somehow. This is as far as I have gotten, the echo was a test to see if the process worked...it did not.

I was thinking that I could do a form action to create the array, then process that array giving me a number that could then be passed to the shopping cart.

```
if (isset($post['h'])){
    $a=array(h);
    echo array_sum($a);
    }
```

Exam Study Guide - Add $100.00
        Online Test Simulator - Add $100.00

Comment: This part was cut off:

Answer (score 0):

One of the most basic versions that might push you is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="exam_study_guide" value="100">Exam Study Guide<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="online_test_simulator" value="200">Online Test Simulator<br/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {   

    // example of calculating the sum
    $sum = 0;
    if(!empty($_POST['online_test_simulator'])) {
        $sum += $_POST['online_test_simulator'];
    }    

    if(!empty($_POST['exam_study_guide'])) {
        $sum += $_POST['exam_study_guide'];
    }

    // perform many other different actions like add to cart etc.

}
```

Here you have two checkboxes, submition via POST where you can get the data and do further things with it

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!  I am new to this complexity, I tried to do an echo so I could see what was in the array:echo $_POST; but nothing happened.  How would I get the values into the shopping cart? - 
<form action="https://*****.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>